# Returning true for strings that begin with a hashtag using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm confused why in http://regexr.com/3bcns, my `^#` isn't matching `#hello-link`, which is a string that begins with a hashtag.

This is what I want to do:

```
if ((/^\.\./).test(link)) { 
alert('link starts with ..');
} else if (!(/#/).test(link)) {
alert('does not contain #');
} else if ((/^#/).test(link))  { 
alert('link begins with a #');
}
```

Also, I'm curious: is there any reason why people prefer to use `.test` instead of `.match` when using regexes in javascript?

Comment: add the multiline flag (`/m`) ?

Comment: For your test sample, you have to use the _multi-line_ option.  Otherwise, `^` means _Beginning of String_. If you're testing the JS and the hash tag can be anywhere in the string, either at the beginning, or after a newline, be sure to set `/^#/m`

Comment: Do you mean there is a multiline option in http://regexr.com/?

Comment: yes under flags menu top right of the page

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't think to check under the flags option.

Comment: also `String.match` will return an array whereas `Regexp.test` will return a boolean, which might be enough in most cases and doesn't need further test, and is also less slow. For a better alternative, you could use `String.search` which will return the index of the finding or `-1` if none.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the first character of the string?

```
function start_with_hash(str){
  return str[0]=='#';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.test(str)` returns a Boolean telling whether or not a match is present. This is the most straightforward check to perform if the only thing you care about is whether or not a match exists.

`String.match(regex)` returns the text of the match, or null if there is no match. This is more useful if you need to know what the match actually is. (Edited to reflect Oriol's correction.)

Comment: `string.match(regex)` returns `null` if there is no match, not `-1`.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of String.search(regex). I will correct it.